# Set a range of free local ports to application

Tags: c#, tcp, process, range, port

I have a client application that create a socket with random local port, i cant change the code of this application and i want to set a range of the ports he can use from my C# application. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can connect to a listener that uses a random port number.  They can't guess the proper port to use.

Comment: sorry, corrected. I meant that client application uses random local port, and i want to set a range of the ports he can use. But i cant change code of this client application

Answer (score 0):

So the client will try to connect to your application using any one of a range of port numbers. You can't know which socket they will use, but you CAN know they will use one of this range.

If that is the case, you can do one of two things:

1. If the computer on which your app runs only ever has to interact with this one client, then simply set up one TcpListener (or other socket listener) to listen on your address on all ports. This is risky; if some other computer tries to ask for a web page, or tries to set the network time on this comp, your app may incorrectly intercept these connections.
2. If you really do need a range of available ports on which the client can connect, then I would use a for loop to set up a collection of TcpListeners, one for each port on which you wish to connect.

Understand this is for TCP. UDP (another common protocol) is stateless, meaning connections are never created between client and server; the client simply shouts something to that server and port and prays the server is listening, receives and understands the message.

Comment: Thanks! But i cant change the client application code, i think maybe using some APIs i can do this(set range of available ports for client application when he create socket in random port), maybe hook list of free local ports

Comment: Do you have any information about the range of ports the client application will use? I find it hard to believce that the application would communicate on a 100% completely random port, including ones normally reserved like 80 (for webserver traffic via HTTP). Once you know that the client will try to connect on, you can listen on the same ports (even if you have to listen on 60k+ ports). It's by no means ideal, but nothing about this situation is.